# How throw forbidden exception from middleware in laravel5?

Tags: php, exception, laravel, middleware, laravel-5

I am writing a middleware in laravel 5. I want to throw a forbidden exception with code 403 from middleware. My middleware function is given below:

```
use Exception;

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!Auth::check()) {
        throw new Exception("Access denied", 403);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

I am calling my middleware from controller and I am getting error message with code 500 but not 403. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 57):

You can simply use the `abort()` helper. (Or `App::abort()`)

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    if (!Auth::check()) {
        abort(403, 'Access denied');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

---

You can handle these exceptions inside `App\Exceptions\Handler` by overriding `render()` For example:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if($e instanceof HttpException && $e->getStatusCode() == 403){
        return new JsonResponse($e->getMessage(), 403);
    }    
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Comment: thank you.. I am developing REST APIs,so I want to generate json response.How it is possible?

Comment: I want to catch all these from exception  handler as like `if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException || $e instanceof NotFoundHttpException || $e instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {   return new JsonResponse($error_response, 404);
        }`

Comment: It is not working,but I have written some my own exception classes and now I am using the same.

Comment: Did you `use` the `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException`? Because that's what `abort()` throws.